# The 'click' binding is not working - unable to call the function -- Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following in my View:

```html
<div data-bind='foreach: providers'>
  <div data-bind='text: name'></div>
  <button data-bind='click: model.addToCart'>Show</button>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th style="width: 300px">Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: items'>
      <tr>
        <td data-bind='text: name'></td>
        <td data-bind='text: price'></td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" data-bind='click: model.add' value="Add">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the following in my model:

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  self.providers = data; //some random array data
  self.addToCart = function(place) {
    console.log(place);
  }
};
```

I have used the normal `click` binding in the Knockout.js.

When I run the code, it seems that the addToCart function is not even being called. I get no output from `console.log()` for any value.

What have I missed? I'm a beginner. Please help out.

Comment: is model() a sub-view model?

Comment: `model()` is a view model.

Comment: is that the model for `providers`?

Comment: No. `providers` is defined globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once inside a `foreach` loop, your scope is the object you're currently iterating on. So, to refer to a function in the parent or root scope you're gonna have to use `$root` (although `$parent` is the same in this case):

```
<button data-bind='click: $root.addToCart'>Show</button>
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: But I've used `model.addToCart`. Is that not enough?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed, No. `model` means nothing to Knockout when it comes to interpret your expression (it will look for a `model` *property* in your current `provider`). If you want to access your root view-model, use `$root` (as stated explicitly in the link I provided).

Comment: And what if I want to use a function that is present in some other Model?? Like `someOtherModel.addToCart`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll go through the link.

Comment: Knockout is only able to (directly) work with the object you provided in the `ko.applyBindings()` call. If you need to access some data outside the scope of your view-model (although not recommended), you can try `window.someGlobalVariable`. But it's still recommended to expose that external data in some method as part of your view-model.

Answer (score 1):

your parent View Model should have

```
var self = this;
self.providers = ko.observableArray();
self.model = new Model();
```

then in your foreach loop you can use

```
$root.model.addToCart()
```

Comment: Yeah.. I understood that I missed the word `$root` or `$parent`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh, I thought you would have marked @haim770 answer as correct then, my mistake

Comment: Yeah.. I still have 12 seconds to go for marking it correct. :). That's it. Thanks again!